# How to install a module as an egg under IronPython?

Tags: python, ironpython, egg

Maybe, it is a stupid question but I can't use python eggs with IronPython.

I would like to test with IronPython 2.0.2 one module that I've developped. This modules is pure python. It works ok with python 2.6 and is installed as a python egg thanks to setuptools.

I thought that the process for installing my module under IronPython was very similar but unfortunately it doesn't work.

I can't install setuptools-0.6c9 with IronPython (Crash of IronPython). I've tried to copy manually my egg under IronPython site-packages and it doesn't work either.

I've also tried to include the python 2.6 site-package in the IronPython path but it can't load my module.

I've made some tests with other modules and it seems that IronPython can not load eggs. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it's still not possible - it's work in progress. See [this post](http://ironpython-urls.blogspot.com/2009/01/jeff-hardy-django-zlib-and-easyinstall.html), for example. IronPython's main strength is in integration with the .NET ecosystem - it's not a drop-in replacement for CPython. See [this post](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/02/26/ironpython-is-a-one-way-gate/) for some other limitations of IronPython.