# Has anyone managed to install Python modules using Iron Python?

Tags: .net, python, linux, module, ironpython

I have been trawling the net looking for info on installing Python modules (eg. Setuptools) into Iron Python. The general consensus was that it was a work in progress a couple of years ago. Has anyone has any luck?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: There has been some work last year on [porting NumPy and SciPy on IronPython](http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumPy%20and%20SciPy%20for%20.Net), but there hasn't been much further development. I've tested these briefly and at least I am able to import and run some simple test without problems. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use CPython modules with IronPython.
It is possible to use regular Python scripts as long as they are not importing any C modules.
The Idea with Iron Python is to use .NET assemblies. And for an equivalent you will probably be using something like [Nuget](http://nuget.org/) in .NET and just reference and import the .NET assemblies.

Also I think your question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187110/how-to-install-a-module-as-an-egg-under-ironpython).